# Can I filter directories using glob pattern?

Tags: java

I have this example code:

```
String myGlobFilter = /*whatever*/;
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(myPathToLookIn, myGlobFilter);
```

Is it possible that the stream includes directories only just by changing `myGlobFilter`? How would `myGlobFilter` look like? I tried `*/`, but it still includes files.

Answer (score 1):

Glob patterns don't distinguish between directories and non-directory paths.

If you want to get only directories, you can use [this other form of `newDirectoryStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.DirectoryStream.Filter)) with [a `DirectoryStream.Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.Filter.html) like this:

```
DirectoryStream<Path> directories = Files.newDirectoryStream(myPathToLookIn, p -> Files.isDirectory(p, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue is, this is the code of an api endpoint. I wanted to know if I can achieve to filter directories without changing the endpoint, which would obviously be preferred. Guess the endpoint must be changed then.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if it's doable with using a globbing pattern. But it can be definitely done using another overloaded version of [`Files.newDirectoryStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.DirectoryStream.Filter)) that expects [`DirectoryStream.Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.Filter.html) as the second argument:

```
Path myPathToLookIn = // path
DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> filter = Files::isDirectory;
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(myPathToLookIn, filter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue is, this is the code of an api endpoint. I wanted to know if I can achieve to filter directories without changing the endpoint, which would obviously be preferred. Guess the endpoint must be changed then.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm The fewer changes, the better, it's understandable. But it seems like it's not possible. Also, glob patterns are sensitive to the hosting system, whilst code dialing only with the `Path` interface can be implemented as system-agnostic.